# How to get image dimensions before it's lazy loaded using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, lazy-loading

#### The goal:

I have a set of images in a container which has a height of 0. When the trigger is clicked I want the container to slide down (animated) and lazy load the images in (using the lazy load jQuery plugin).

#### The Markup:

```
<a href="#">Trigger 1</a>

<div class="container-1">
    <img data-src="http://actualimageurl.jpg" src="http://loadinggif.gif">
    <img data-src="http://actualimageurl.jpg" src="http://loadinggif.gif">
    <img data-src="http://actualimageurl.jpg" src="http://loadinggif.gif">
</div>

<a href="#">Trigger 2</a>

<div class="container-2">
    <img data-src="http://actualimageurl.jpg" src="http://loadinggif.gif">
    <img data-src="http://actualimageurl.jpg" src="http://loadinggif.gif">
    <img data-src="http://actualimageurl.jpg" src="http://loadinggif.gif">
</div>

// ETC
```

#### The Problem:

In order to animate the container I need to give it a height. Currently I use jQuery quickly to get the height of the container, store it in a data-height attribute and then animate the height to zero. The problem is that it is getting the height based on the loading gif's inside when the image that will actually be loaded might be much taller. So the data-height attribute might be 600px when the fully loaded container will be 2000px.

Should/Can I:

1. Get the height of the image stored in the data-src attribute before it is lazy loaded in, add those together, then set the container to that height.
2. Keep the container closed, load in each image, once their loaded I can add them together, calculate the container height, then slide it down (not ideal as it'll be very slow).
3. Any other suggestions?

#### The Kicker:

This site will be responsive so the fully loaded images' height will vary based on browser width as they have a max-width: 100%;

Answer (score 0):

> Get the height of the image stored in the data-src attribute before it is lazy loaded in, add those together, then set the container to that height.

Yes, because it is given that the width does not change. If it saves your time, you can also investigate plugins like [imagesloaded](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded) and [lazyload](http://www.appelsiini.net/lazyload).

Comment: But the height will change? if the image is 1000x1000 and the browser width is 500 then the image height will be 500 too

Answer (score 0):

You could lazy load the images into a div that's position fixed way off the user's browser window, then once the image has loaded, find it's height and give the div you want to fill the image with a height of zero, replace the background-image of that div, then animate it to the height you learned from the div offscreen

Comment: Good idea. Sorry I should've mentioned there are several triggers and several images containers (it's a portfolio), so loading the images if the container isn't opened isn't practical

Comment: Is your goal to load the images one by one into the box, animating as you go? Like you'd start with a height of "gif image height" * 3 and then end with a height of "sum of all image heights"?

Comment: Ideally I'd like to give the container the "sum of all image heights" so that the container isn't jumping around as image image loads in

Comment: I think something that would look smooth then, is having one loading gif for the container, then after all three images are loaded, doing a sort of 1,2,3 animation effect to bring them all in. Otherwise what you're looking for isn't really possible without knowing details about the images ahead of time.